# How to architect array of promises in GraphQL resolver with multiple API calls to return a single object type list

Tags: javascript, promise, graphql

I'm stuck in my GraphQL resolver fetching todo-lists for a particular user belonging to a company. According to whether or not they have access to all todo-lists or a certain few, it will fetch for groups the user registered to that have belonging todo-lists, and those should be fetched.

The code so far is capable of logging the requested todo-lists on the query but I have yet to come to the solution on how to actually return data of all of the user's registered groups's todo-lists.

I chose to export the actual logic into a separate function

The Resolver:

```
allowedListItems: {
  type: new GraphQLList(TodoItem),
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    return Promise.all([fetchAllowedItems(parentValue._id)]);
  }
},
```

The Promise Function

```
function fetchAllowedItems(userId) {
  return User.findOne({ _id: userId }).then((user) => {
    if (user.todoGroups) {
      return user.todoGroups.map((groupId) => {
        return TodoGroup.findOne({ _id: groupId }).then(group => {
          return group.todoLists.map((listId) => {
            return TodoList.findOne({ _id: listId })
          })
        })
      })
    } else {
      return TodoList.find({ company: parentValue.company }).exec();
    }
  })
}
```

I am not getting any errors from GraphQL so I guess it's about the way I make the promisses return to the resolver, I'd appreciate a lot if you can help me out!

Update:

I should wrap the maps with a Promise.all, as the mapping returns an array.
Though the updated code brings no improvement in the returned data.

```
async resolve(parentValue, args) {
    let user = await User.findOne({ _id: parentValue._id })

    if (user.todoGroups) {
      return Promise.all(user.todoGroups.map((groupId) => {
        return TodoGroup.findOne({ _id: groupId }).then(group => {
          return Promise.all(group.todoLists.map((listId) => {
            return TodoList.findOne({ _id: listId });
          }))
        })
      }))
    } else {
      return TodoList.find({ company: parentValue.company }).exec();
    }
  }
},
```

Current query result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "_id": "5ba11690ad7a93d2b34d21a9",
      "allowedTodos": [
        {
          "_id": null,
          "title": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating promise for arrays of promises for arrays of promises. You'll likely want to wrap each `map` call creating such an array of promises in `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Promise.all` on an array of promises, not a promise for that. Also you'll have to call it on each level:

```
allowedListItems: {
  type: new GraphQLList(TodoItem),
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    return User.findOne({ _id: parentValue._id }).then(user => {
      if (user.todoGroups) {
        return Promise.all(user.todoGroups.map(groupId => {
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
          return TodoGroup.findOne({ _id: groupId }).then(group => {
            return Promise.all(group.todoLists.map(listId => {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
              return TodoList.findOne({ _id: listId })
            }));
          });
        }));
      } else {
        return TodoList.find({ company: parentValue.company }).exec();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: After implementing your suggested changes I still get 'null' data back from the query.

Comment: @AnthonyLimere Maybe that's when `TodoList.find` cannot find something? Otherwise, you should at least get arrays of `null` results.

Comment: TodoList.findOne / .find does return the object -> .then(e => console.log(e))

Comment: (You should do `.then(e => { console.log(e); return e; })` or `.then(e => (console.log(e), e))` to avoid fulfilling with `undefined`)

Comment: Then where exactly are you getting `null` data? As far I can see, that could only be a problem with your data(base), not with the promise chaining.

Comment: `{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "_id": "5ba11690ad7a93d2b34d21a9",
      "allowedTodos": [
        {
          "_id": null,
          "title": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: interestingly enough the data exists and is retrieved because it can be logged as is, thanks for the trick btw, also the GraphQL Object Type is consistent with the data

Comment: Your answer hasn't solved it yet sorry it that wasn't clear :|

Comment: @AnthonyLimere the code in the question does not deal with `.allowedTodos` *anywhere*. That array with the null-containing object is coming straight from your database. If you want to handle them, add another `.then()` (or use `await`) to the promise and manipulate the property as you want.